# when launching an EC2, can I include a script file with arguments in user_data field?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

when launching an EC2, can I include a script file with arguments in user_data field? 
such as:
    user_data = "${file("install_software.sh"), user_name pass_word}"

besides, can I include multiple script files in user_data field? such as:
    user_data = "${file("install_software1.sh","install_software2.sh")}"

I did not see any examples of them yet, so I do not know what can be the format. If I cannot do that using user_data, how to do that? should I use remote-exec or sth. else?

============= update:
Thanks KOE for responding me. Here I post the complete answers in case sb. else need. I have tested them.

+++++++++++ how to include arguments in user_data field:

userdata_arguments_test.tf:

```
data "template_file" "user_data_test" {
      template = "${file("userdata_arg_test.tfl")}"
      vars {
        myuser = "${var.myuser}"
        mypassword = "${var.mypassword}"
      }
}
resource "aws_instance" "user_data_test" {
......
  user_data = "${data.template_file.user_data_test.rendered}"
}
```

userdata_arg_test.tfl

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ${myuser}, ${mypassword} >/tmp/my_info.log
```

+++++++++++ how to include multiple files in user_data field:

userdata_mfiles_test.tf:

```
 data "template_file" "user_data_common" {
  template = "${file("userdata_arg_test.tfl")}"
  vars {
    myuser = "${var.myuser}"
    mypassword = "${var.mypassword}"
  }
}
data "template_file" "user_data_master" {
  template = "${file("userdata_arg_test2.tfl")}"
  vars {
    myuser2 = "${var.myuser}"
    mypassword2 = "${var.mypassword}"
  }
}
data "template_cloudinit_config" "master" {
  gzip          = true
  base64_encode = true

 part {
   content_type = "text/x-shellscript"
   content      = "${data.template_file.user_data_common.rendered}"
 }

  part {
    content_type = "text/x-shellscript"
    content      = "${data.template_file.user_data_master.rendered}"
  }
}
resource "aws_instance" "user_data_test" {
  ....
  user_data     = "${data.template_cloudinit_config.master.rendered}"
}
```

userdata_arg_test.tfl

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ${myuser}, ${mypassword} >/tmp/my_info.log
```

userdata_arg_test2.tfl

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ${myuser2} + ${mypassword2} >/tmp/my_info2.log
```

Comment: This question, as it stands, isn't particularly clear. Are the scripts already on the instance when it is provisioned or are you wanting to execute them remotely? What have you tried already?

Comment: ydaetsknoR: I want to upload and execute scripts when launching EC2. I know I can add user_data = "${file("install_software.sh")}" when launching an EC2. but do not know how to execute a script which has arguments. and I do not know how to execute multiple scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks KOE for responding me. Here I post the complete answers in case sb. else need. I have tested them.

## How to include arguments in user_data field

**userdata_arguments_test.tf:**

```
data "template_file" "user_data_test" {
      template = "${file("userdata_arg_test.tfl")}"
      vars {
        myuser = "${var.myuser}"
        mypassword = "${var.mypassword}"
      }
}

resource "aws_instance" "user_data_test" {
......
  user_data = "${data.template_file.user_data_test.rendered}"
}
```

**userdata_arg_test.tfl**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ${myuser}, ${mypassword} >/tmp/my_info.log
```

## How to include multiple files in user_data field

**userdata_mfiles_test.tf:**

```
 data "template_file" "user_data_common" {
  template = "${file("userdata_arg_test.tfl")}"
  vars {
    myuser = "${var.myuser}"
    mypassword = "${var.mypassword}"
  }
}

data "template_file" "user_data_master" {
  template = "${file("userdata_arg_test2.tfl")}"
  vars {
    myuser2 = "${var.myuser}"
    mypassword2 = "${var.mypassword}"
  }
}

data "template_cloudinit_config" "master" {
  gzip          = true
  base64_encode = true

 part {
   content_type = "text/x-shellscript"
   content      = "${data.template_file.user_data_common.rendered}"
 }

  part {
    content_type = "text/x-shellscript"
    content      = "${data.template_file.user_data_master.rendered}"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "user_data_test" {
  ....
  user_data     = "${data.template_cloudinit_config.master.rendered}"
}
```

**userdata_arg_test.tfl**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ${myuser}, ${mypassword} >/tmp/my_info.log
```

**userdata_arg_test2.tfl**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ${myuser2} + ${mypassword2} >/tmp/my_info2.log
```

Comment: works like a charm! Thank you. I was missing #!/bin/bash

Answer (score 4):

What you want to use is `template_file`

```
data "template_file" "user_data" {
  template = "${file("script1.sh.tpl")}"

  vars {
    var1 = "foo"
    var2 = "bar"
  }
}
```

If you want to use multiple scripts in your user_data you need to follow the cloud-init multipart format and put it in one or several file *.tpl, then combine them using terraform standard interpolation or inline templates.

Reference:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/d/file.html
http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/format.html#mime-multi-part-archive
https://github.com/ukayani/cloud-init-example/blob/master/SampleUserData

Comment: Hi, Koe, sorry I still did not get it. will learn how to use template on user_data and let you know. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Koe, Thanks, I understand how to use it now.